# Trying to wp_enqueue multiple files fails

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add multiple css and js files in functions.php with this code:

```
function custom_files() {
wp_register_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_register_style( 'pageone', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/pageone.css', array(), '1', 'all' );
wp_register_style( 'pagetwo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/pagetwo.css', array(), '1', 'all' );
wp_register_style( 'reset', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/reset.css', array(), '1', 'all' );

wp_register_script('loader', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/loader.js', array('jquery'), '', FALSE);
wp_register_script('main-scripts', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/main-scripts.js', array('jquery'), '', TRUE);

wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'reset' );

wp_enqueue_script('loader');
wp_enqueue_script('main-scripts');

if ( is_page('6')) {
    wp_enqueue_style('pageone');
}

if ( is_page('8')) {
    wp_enqueue_style('pagetwo');
}

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_files' );
```

It loads only style.css file. Why is that?

Comment: Code looks correct check your network tab to make sure the files are resolving.

Comment: Where exactly is your function placed? Chances are it is never run (and `style.css` is loaded because it's default theme behavior - it's enqueued by default). The simplest way to check is to place a `die('got here!')` in your function. If its run, check for any 404 errors in your browser. It's possible the paths don't resolve correctly. Also, make sure you don't have any caching plugins active when developing.

Comment: if you files are in the child them, then it should be clear: you're trying to load files from parent theme using `get_template_directory_uri()`. but you should to call files from child theme using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` function

Answer (score 0):

If you are in child theme, as rightly mentioned by Samvel, make sure that you are adding css from right location. Means if your css is in child theme use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() for child theme path.

get_template_directory_uri() function is called to access parent theme path. So chances are you are trying to add a file which do not exist at the defined place.